# on a recursive sequence (exercise 8.14 Apostol).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

The exercise asks to prove convergence and find the limit of the sequence:$$a_n= \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n},\text{ where } b_1=b_2 =1, b_{n+2} = b_{n} + b_{n+1}. $$

It also gives a hint: Show that  $ \ b_{n+2}b_n - b_{n+1}^2 = (-1)^{n+1}$ by induction.

I am having problems proving $ \ b_{n+2}b_n - b_{n+1}^2 = (-1)^{n+1}$ by induction, could I have a helping hand?

Comment: I don't think I will spoil anything be mentioning that the $b_n$ are what is called the [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), and what you are told is to find the [limit of consecutive quotients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Limit_of_consecutive_quotients).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $u_n=b_{n+2}b_n-b_{n+1}^2$. We have $u_n=\begin{vmatrix}b_n&b_{n+1}\cr b_{n+1}&b_{n+2}\end{vmatrix}$ hence
$$u_{n+1}=\begin{vmatrix}b_{n+1}&b_{n+2}\cr b_{n+2}&b_{n+3}\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}b_{n+1}&b_n+b_{n+1}\cr b_{n+2}&b_{n+1}+b_{n+2}\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}b_{n+1}&b_{n}\cr b_{n+2}&b_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}=-u_n$$
Then it is easy.

Answer (score 4):

$$b_{n+3}b_{n+1}-b_{n+2}^2= (b_{n+2}+b_{n+1})b_{n+1}-b_{n+2}^2 = (b_{n+1}-b_{n+2})b_{n+2} + b^2_{n+1} = (b_{n+1}-b_{n+2})(b_{n+1} + b_n) + b^2_{n+1}= 2b^2_{n+1}-b_{n+2}b_{n+1} +b_{n+1}b_n -b_{n+2}b_n = (b^2_{n+1}-b_{n+2}b_n)+b^2_{n+1}-b_{n+2}b_{n+1} +b_{n+1}b_n$$

Now note that $$b^2_{n+1}-b_{n+2}b_{n+1} +b_{n+1}b_n = b_{n+1}(b_{n+1}+b_n-b_{n+2}) = 0$$

and therefore you get that $$b_{n+3}b_{n+1}-b_{n+2}^2= (b^2_{n+1}-b_{n+2}b_n)+b^2_{n+1}-b_{n+2}b_{n+1} +b_{n+1}b_n = -(b_{n+2}b_n-b^2_{n+1}) = -(-1)^{n+1} = (-1)^{n+2}$$

Comment: What kind of approach did you adopt in this proof? To me your second and third inequalities are not intuitive. Could you explain me how did you throw out of your hat the second and third equalities please?

Comment: The second equality comes from the fact that $$b_{n+2} = b_{n+1}+b_{n}$$ and therefore $$-b_{n+2} + b_{n+1}+b_{n} = 0$$

The third, is by using the first and the second equalities, and the induction asummption.

Comment: I meant these equalities $$(b_{n+2}+b_{n+1})b_{n+1}-b_{n+2}^2 = (b_{n+1}-b_{n+2})b_{n+2} + b^2_{n+1} = (b_{n+1}-b_{n+2})(b_{n+1} + b_n) + b^2_{n+1}$$although I can understand them, I would like to ask you how and why you rearranged them in that way. Did you have a particular aim or you were just "trying something" with algebra?

Comment: Just tried to get a form that I could use the recursive defenition, and the induction assumption